# Calculate Subtraction of diagonals-summations in a two-dimensional matrix using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*I am practing at hackerrank and I have an exercise with 
two-dimensional matrix. I am facing an error in my implementation*

- 11 2 4
- 4 5 6
- 10 8 -12

I need to sum across the primary diagonal: 11 + 5 - 12 = 4 after the other diagonal 4 + 5 +10 = 19 finally 19 - 4 = 15

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
     var sumRigth = 0;
     var sumLeft = 0;
     var array = new Array();
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++ ){
          for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
               array.push(arr[i][j]);
          }
     }
     for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i = i + 4){
          sumRigth += array[i];
     }
     for (var j = 2 ; j < array.length - 1 ; j = j + 2 ){
          sumLeft += array[j];
     }
     return sumLeft - sumRigth;
}
```

Comment: Minor note: no experienced JS dev would write `var array = new Array();` ... they'd write `var array = [];` ... but typically they would use a variable name that is meaningful/helpful, like say `var matrix = [];`

Comment: thanks for the tip !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
function sumDiagonal(matrix) {

    let firstSum = 0, secondSum = 0;
    for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        firstSum += matrix[row][row];
        secondSum += matrix[row][matrix.length - row - 1];
    }
    console.log(firstSum + ' ' + secondSum);
    console.log(firstSum-secondSum);
}

sumDiagonal([[11,2,4],[4,5,6],[10,8,-12]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're on the right path. A general solution would first sum the elements from top-left to bottom-right (saved here as `sumRigth`). Then, sum the elements from top-right to bottom-left (saved here as `sumLeft`). I took it for granted that arrays contain numbers and are of the same size.

```js
function diagonalDifference(array) {
     let sumRigth = 0, sumLeft = 0, count = 0;
     for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
          sumRigth += array[i][count++];
     }
     count = array.length-1;
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          sumLeft += array[i][count--];
     }
     return sumLeft - sumRigth;
}

let arr = [
     [11, 2, 4],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [10, 8, -12]
];
console.log(diagonalDifference(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and get two values dierctly for summing.

```js
function getValue(matrix) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0, l = matrix.length; i < l; i++)
        sum += matrix[i][l - i - 1] - matrix[i][i];

    return sum;
}

console.log(getValue([[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]));
```